# using semaphores in C

Tags: c, unix

### a.c

```
union semun{
  int val;
  struct senid_ds *buf;
  unsigned short *array;
};
union semun arg;

int func(){
 key_sem = ftok(".",67);
        if(FAILURE == key_sem){
                perror("\n key_sem:");
                return FAILURE;
        }
        key_val++;
        semid = semget(key_sem,1,IPC_CREAT);
        if(FAILURE == semid){
                perror("\n semid:");
                return FAILURE;
        }
        printf("\n Key : %d Semaphore ID is : %d \n",key_sem,semid);
    arg.val = 1;
    ret = semctl(semid,0,SETVAL,arg);

}
```

### b.c

```
int ret;
struct sembuf op[1];

int read_pos(){

     op[0].sem_num = 0;
     op[0].sem_op = -1;
     op[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

     printf("\n gng to lock! \n");
     printf("\n semid: %d \n",details.sem_id);

     ret = semop(details.sem_id,op,1);
     printf("\n Locked! \n");

     sleep(15);


     op[0].sem_op = 1;
     ret = semop(details.sem_id,op,1);
     printf("\n Unlocked! \n");

    return SUCCESS;
}

int main(){
 read_pos();
 return 0;
}
```

I created 2 binaries one with sleep in the read(pro) and the other without sleep(a.out).

First executed ./pro
then ./a.out

Though pro has acquired Locked. a.out could also acquire the lock. It should not acquire the lock.
I tried prinitng the semaphore ID. Its the same. What might be the cause ?

Comment: First of all, try passing `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL` to `semget()`. A proper example of using semaphores is available [**here**](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html#semsamp).

Comment: Thanks TheCodeArtist. Its a very good link.